# Core Data группировка результатов с использованием маски

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, coredata

Имеется вот такой SQL запрос:

```
SELECT `quadKey`, MIN(id) AS id, COUNT(id) AS count, AVG(longitude) AS longitude, AVG(latitude) AS latitude 
FROM marker 
WHERE quadKey between 15499682906112 and 15499683168255 
GROUP BY (quadKey & 15499683151872);
```

Подскажите, как перенести его на Objective-C, а именно интересует как применить к оператору GROUP BY маску. Вот часть моего кода:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"GBVenue"];

NSExpressionDescription *countExpressionDescription = [self expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"priority"]] resultName:@"count" resultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];

....

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"quadKey", countExpressionDescription, minIdExpressionDescription, averageLongitudeExpressionDescription, averageLatitudeExpressionDescription, minLongitudeExpressionDescription, minLatitudeExpressionDescription, maxLongitudeExpressionDescription, maxLatitudeExpressionDescription]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"quadKey"]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```